# Mobile inbox incorrectly links messages from Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, mobile-web, global-inbox

When viewing the mobile site, inbox messages from the Careers site do not properly link to their related content.

When the Careers message is the most recent message, it has no link destination at all.  When there is a newer message, the careers message links to the newer message's related content even though it is unrelated to the Careers message.  This only happens with Careers messages.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

At display time (mobile only) we just weren't setting a variable with the proper link for careers messages, so we'd use the *last* link rendered (if you'd had an otherwise empty inbox you'd have seen javascript errors).

Root cause, dynamism and javascripts stupid function scoping for variables.  Also, my sucky code.